# Inner array in the result of SQL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to get the result of sql with array inside array

Table A

```
Name   Organisation     Date      CheckIN      Checkout 
AA       BB           01.07.10     09:00          11:00
AA       BB           01.07.10     13:00          14:00
AA       BB           01.07.10     15:00          16:00
AA       BB           02.07.10     08:00          11:00
AA       BB           03.07.10     11:00          12:00
CC       FF           01.07.10     07:00          10:00
CC       FF           04.07.10     09:00          11:00
CC       FF           05.07.10     12:00          13:00
CC       FF           06.07.10     09:00          11:00
```

```
Array {

[1] Name1, Organisation, Array { [11] date, checkin, checkout 
                                 [12] date, checkin, checkout }
[2] Name2, Organisation, Array { [21] date, checkin, checkout 
                                 [22] date, checkin, checkout }
[3] Name4, Organisation, Array { [31] date, checkin, checkout 
                                 [32] date, checkin, checkout }
[4] Name5, Organisation, Array { [41] date, checkin, checkout 
                                 [42] date, checkin, checkout }
}
```

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays, so this is not possible.

Comment: The output you seem to want looks a lot like JSON.  Can you show us that output with values based off the sample input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support arrays, but you can concatenate this as a string:

```
select name, organization,
       group_concat(date, ',', checkin, ',' checkout separator ';')
from t
group by name, organization;
```

Comment: I was looking for anyother solution than concat :(